# Finding a curious limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> Find the limit:
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} (1+ \sin(t))^{1/t} dt.$$

A hint that has been given is to use L'Hospital's Rule. Moreover, it must be substantiated why we can use L'Hospital' Rule in this situation. It is also important to mention that $(1 + \sin(t))$ has a removable point of discontinuity at $0$ and therefore the integral can be interpreted as a Riemann integral.

Comment: the Limit is $e$

Comment: Why asking twice exactly the same question?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? If you are not satisfied with answers to the original question then ask for more clarification in comments to the answers rather than just copy pasting the question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} (1+ \sin(t))^{1/t} dt$, then the given limit is $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(0)=\lim_{t\to0}(1+ \sin(t))^{1/t}=\lim_{t\to0}\left((1+ \sin(t))^{1/\sin t}\right)^{\sin t/t}$$
As $\sin t\to 0$ as $t\to0$, hence $\lim_{t\to 0}(1+ \sin(t))^{1/\sin t}=e$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$

Comment: This is not quite right even though the number is right.  You need to have the $(\sin t)/t$ limit separately proven (or referenced) to equal $1$; that does not follow from this analysis.

Comment: as @Oscar said this is not totally correct. However you can fix it writing $$\lim_{t\to 0^+} (1+\sin t)^{1/t}=\exp\left(\lim_{t\to 0^+}t^{-1}\ln(1+\sin t)\right)=e$$ what can be shown from the expansion of $\ln (1+x)$ and the expansion of $\sin t$.

Comment: Thanks.  Go ahead and incorporate that into the answer.

Comment: Contrary to what @OscarLanzi is saying, this is totally correct. The last sentence in the answer is a justification for the fact that the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}(1+\sin t) ^{1/t}=e$

Comment: @Paramanand yes but as it reads it seems that we can conclude that $\lim_{t\to 0}\sin t/t=1$ from the assumption that $\lim_{t\to 0}(1+\sin t) ^{1/t}=e$. This is what Oscar pointed out. The other way around is the correct one, that is what you said.

Comment: Agree @Masacroso. I hope this minor issue is fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

One way to compute the limit consist in computing the integral first. Now
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{x} (1+ \sin(t))^{1/t} dt = \int_{0}^{x} e (1-\frac{t}{2} +\frac{7}{24} t^2-\frac{3}{16} t^3+ \frac{139}{1152} t^4+ ...) dt= e x (1-\frac{1}{4} x+\frac{7}{72} x^2-\frac{3}{64} x^3+ \frac{139}{5760} x^4+ ...) 
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} (1+ \sin(t))^{1/t} dt=\lim_{x\to 0}  [e(1-\frac{1}{4} x+\frac{7}{72} x^2-\frac{3}{64} x^3+ \frac{139}{5760} x^4+ ...) ] = e 
\end{equation}